# How to set Dropdownlist value to Textboxfor on each row when add dynamically in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Good morning, I am creating a project in MVC I am just learning to use it.
 But my question is how to place the selected value of a dropdownlist in a textbox when I generate it dynamically?
 I share the GIF that I made so that it shows better what I mean.

[Table Issue with Dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhDvV.gif)

And here is my view code:

```
@model List<MvcApplication30.TB_CS_TEST>

<style>
    th {
        text-align:left;
    }
    td {
    padding:5px;
}
</style>
<div style="width:700px; padding:5px; background-color:white;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Bulk","Bulk", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        if (ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
            <div style="border:solid 1px green">
                @ViewBag.Message
            </div>
        }

        <div><a href="#" id="addNew">Add Product</a></div>
        <table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
            @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
            {

                int j = 0;
                foreach (var i in Model.GroupBy(a => a.CONTACTID))
                {


                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].CONTACTNO)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DropDownList("DESCRIPTION" ,"Select Description")</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a[j].CONTACTPERSON, new { id = "proli"})</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (j > 0)
                            {
                                <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                            }
                        </td>

                    j++;
                }
            }
         </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Save Bulk Data" />
          @Html.DropDownList("NAMEPLACE", "Select Place")
    }
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


@* Here I will add Jquery Code for validation / dynamically add new rows / Remove rows etc *@

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var last = $('#dataTable>tbody>tr:last');
                if (last.length > 0) {
                    var name = last.children().find('input,select')[0].name;
                    var index = Number(name.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')) + 1;
                    var tr = ('<tr>' + last.html().replace(/[0-9]+__/gi, index + '__') + '</tr>').replace(/\[[0-9]+\]+[.]/gi, '[' + index + '].');
                    $('#dataTable tbody').append(tr);
                }
            });
            $('#DESCRIPTION').change(function (e) {
                {
                    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                    $('#proli').val(selectedValue);
                }
            });

        });


    </script>
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this code you are using same id `#DESCRIPTION` `#proli` for dynamic fields, id is always unique through out the page. Try to use class

```
$('#DESCRIPTION').change(function (e) {
                {
                    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                    $('#proli').val(selectedValue);
                }
            });
```

Below code is updated code.  used id as a class, only you have to change your id to class in html

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#addNew").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var last = $('#dataTable>tbody>tr:last');
                if (last.length > 0) {
                    var name = last.children().find('input,select')[0].name;
                    var index = Number(name.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')) + 1;
                    var tr = ('<tr>' + last.html().replace(/[0-9]+__/gi, index + '__') + '</tr>').replace(/\[[0-9]+\]+[.]/gi, '[' + index + '].');
                    $('#dataTable tbody').append(tr);
                }
            });
            $('#dataTable').on("change",'.DESCRIPTION',function (e) {
                {
                    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

                     $(this).closest("tr").find('.proli').val(selectedValue);
                }
            });

        });
``
```

Comment: Hi Kamlesh Bhurke, When you mentioned "Use class" do you mean add class in "Dropdown" or "Textbox"? Thanks.

Comment: yes, use class instead of id in both. or you can use dynamically generated id for e.g. `#DESCRIPTION_1, #DESCRIPTION_2` like this, every id should be unique

Comment: I have updated the code, only change the id to class in html

Comment: Ok let me set a ID in both inside HTML code. I confirm if it works for me or not

Comment: Sorry Kamlesh it doesn't work for me. I just add to my Textbox new { class = "proli"} and DropDown new { class = "DES"}, and jquery is the same as you wrote just only change '.DESCRIPTION' for '.DES'

Comment: I have updated the code now, replace the javascript and change the classes. it will work

Comment: YOU'RE AWESOME! It works perfectly, you saved me from a big problem. Thank you so much!